# Recursive difference equation MATLAB

Tags: matlab, recursion

I have a simple recursive equation, and the idea is for a given starting value of x, trace the future value of x, to see if there any convergence. I wrote a MATLAB code below which is simple, and obviously, x converges to a steady-state value 0.0292 pretty fast.

```
x(1) = 0.2;
for t = 1:1:100
x(t+1) = 0.12*x(t).^0.40;
end
```

However, for more complex equations I do not think I can apply the above code. What if, for example, I have:

```
x(t+1) = 0.12*(x(t)./(x(t+1)+x(t))).^0.40
```

How do I “solve” it to see (without trying to do any algebraic manipulations to isolate x(t+1) on the right-hand-side) to see what the path of x is?
Thank you.

Comment: Use an initial guess for `x(t+1)`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As mentioned in the comments a simple approach would be give an initial guess for `x(t+1)` and try to converge to a solution for `x(t+1)` and then continue iterating.

```
recEq = @(p,q) 0.12 * (p ./ (q+p))^0.4;
x = nan(1, 100);
x(1) = 0.2;
for t = 1:100
    kold = x(t);
    k = recEq(x(t), kold);
    while abs(k-kold) > 1e-8
        kold = k;
        k = recEq(x(t), kold);
    end
    x(t+1) = k;
end
```